# What about this $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x+4}{\sqrt[5]{x^9+3x^4+1}}$?

Tags: calculus

When I saw this limit, I didn't even try to solve it by an algebraic method. I thought about the assyntotic concept.

In the example,

$$\frac{3x+4}{\sqrt[5]{x^9+3x^4+1}}\sim \frac{3x}{\sqrt[5]{x^9}}(x \to \infty)$$

So,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x}{\sqrt[5]{x^9}}=3\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x^{\frac{9}{5}}}=3\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{4}{5}}}=0$$

And then the original limit is equal zero.

Is my thought correct? Would the algebraic method less difficult as I thought?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you're correct.

Comment: @Amire Bendjeddou the $3$ is multiplying the limit. Because $3$ is a constant, I pull it out from the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Both your line of thought and final answer are correct. If you want to be a bit more rigorous, you could proceed as below:

For $x>0$, we have $$x^9 < x^9 + 3x^4 + 1 \implies \sqrt[5]{x^9} < \sqrt[5]{x^9 + 3x^4+1} \implies 0 < \dfrac{3x+4}{\sqrt[5]{x^9 + 3x^4+1}} < \dfrac{3x+4}{\sqrt[5]{x^9}}$$
Now use the squeeze theorem or the sandwich theorem, to conclude what you want.